# In F#, why is there both a List.empty and a List.Empty

Tags: f#

In Visual Studio, Intellisense shows both `List.empty` and `List.Empty`. What's the difference? Why are they both there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[One is a static property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353570.aspx) of the `List` type. [The other is a function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353854.aspx) in the `List` module. They do the same thing. A type with an associated module is a common pattern in F#, and the two frequently overlap, most likely for convenience. Other duplicated members are `IsEmpty`, `Head`, and `Length`.